# Passing NULL xml value to a certain CLR stored function crashes it when called in a certain way

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml, crash, sql-clr

Consider a CLR stored procedure that accepts an XML parameter and calls another stored procedure in the same schema:

```cs
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
     IsDeterministic = false, IsPrecise = true,
     SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlBoolean TestTest(SqlXml Data)
{
    using (var c = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        c.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select case when exists(select 0 from [testing].WillBeCalledByCLR(@d)) then 1 else 0 end;", c))
        {
            var p = cmd.Parameters.Add("@d", SqlDbType.Xml);

            p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            if (Data.IsNull)
                { p.Value = DBNull.Value; }
            else
                { p.Value = Data; }  // Or Data.Value

            return (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

This CLR function is visible in SQL as:

```sql
create function [testing].[TestTest] ( @data xml )
returns bit
WITH CALLED ON NULL INPUT
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [Test].[Test.Test].[TestTest]
```

The stored function it calls is this:

```
create function testing.WillBeCalledByCLR (@x xml = null)
returns table
as
return (
  select 1 as one, 2 as two, 'three' as three
);
```

---

In this setup, if I call the CLR function like this:

```
if testing.TestTest(null) = 1
begin
  select 'Meaningful actions';
end;
```

or like this:

```
declare @res bit = testing.TestTest(null);
```

or like this:

```
declare @res bit;
set @res = testing.TestTest(null);
```

or like this:

```
declare @res bit;
select @res = testing.TestTest(null);
```

then I get:

> Msg 2905, Level 25, State 1, Line 6
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

But if I call it like this:

```
select testing.TestTest(null);
```

or like this:

```
declare @res bit;
set @res = (select testing.TestTest(null));
```

I get a proper value back (e.g. `1`).

If, instead of `null`, I pass an empty string `''`, the function is successfully called in all cases.

Why? Did I do something wrong in my CLR function?

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64)
>   Sep 16 2010 19:43:16
>   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
>   Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (VM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, no, you did not do anything wrong with your .NET code. There *is* a minor technical issue, but we will get to that in a moment.

I was able to reproduce this (both error and non-error scenarios) in SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM. At first, in the "non-error" scenario, I was getting another error for:

> specified cast is invalid

This error was a result of the query passing back an `INT` and the C# code attempting to cast it to a `bool`. I changed the query to be:

```sql
... then CONVERT(BIT, 1) else CONVERT(BIT, 0) end ...
```

That forces the datatype of the value to be returned to be something that can be cast into `bool`. This was the "minor error" that I was referring to, and I consider it "minor" and not really an error because I suspect your code originally attempted to cast into `int` and returned a `SqlInt32` since you claim that passing in an empty string allowed it to return successfully. There is no way this would ever return successfully, even with an empty string instead of `NULL` for the input value, if your code was attempting to cast to `bool` and return `SqlBoolean`. And yes, I could have changed the cast to be `(int)` and the return type to be `SqlInt32`, but this was less of a structural change.

I tested several types of changes: removing the execution, removing the `@d` parameter and hard-coding the `null` into the query but still having the `SqlParameter` defined, removing the `@d` parameter *and* the `SqlParameter`, etc. What it finally came down to is this: **merely the existence of a `SqlParameter` of a LOB type (i.e. `XML`, `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARBINARY(MAX)` ), even if unused in the query, caused the "severe error" when passing in a `NULL`.** However, if any of those `MAX` types were changed to be their maximum non-MAX lengths (i.e. 8000, 4000, and 8000 respectively), then there was no error when passing in a `NULL`. Hence the following reduced code should be enough to reproduce the error when passing in a `NULL` to the SQLCLR scalar function:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 1;", c))
{
    var p = cmd.Parameters.Add("@d", SqlDbType.NVarChar, (int)SqlMetaData.Max);

    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Now, I was *not* able to reproduce the error with the original code in SQL Server 2012 SP3 or SQL Server 2014 SP1 :-). Therefore, I suspect that this was an issue with CLR 2.0 and/or the .NET Framework versions associated with CLR 2.0 (i.e. "2.0", "3.0", and "3.5"). OR, another aspect to consider is that it with this failing ( `declare @res bit; set @res = testing.TestTest(null);` ) while this works ( `declare @res bit; set @res = (select testing.TestTest(null));` ) that could point to a problem with the Query Optimizer and not with the CLR version. Or maybe it is a combination of the two. Or perhaps it is Descartes's pesky [Evil Demon](http://existentialcomics.com/comic/81). Either way. <sup>( ** please see comment at the end )</sup>

If you are able to move up to SQL Server 2012 or newer, then the problem should "magically" disappear. BUT, if stuck on SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2, I was able to work around the issue by declaring the parameter to be a non-MAX type if the input is `NULL`, which should be fine since there won't be any risk of truncation when passing through a `NULL`. And, in the case of the input parameter datatype of the T-SQL object being called being `XML`, it still works to define the parameter datatype in the .NET code as `NVARCHAR(4000)` as it will implicitly convert that into `XML` when called. The following code worked for me in SQL Server 2008 R2 when passing in a `NULL`:

```
SqlParameter _XmlData;

if (Data.IsNull)
{
    // Parameter can't be a LOB type if input is NULL
    _XmlData = new SqlParameter("@d", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
    _XmlData.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    _XmlData = new SqlParameter("@d", SqlDbType.Xml);
    _XmlData.Value = Data.Value;
}

cmd.Parameters.Add(_XmlData);
```

---

****** [@MartinSmith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith) left this illuminating comment:

> Specifically the error seems to be "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000" inside `sqlservr.exe!CClrXvarProxy::EnsureBufferInit` so looks like a null pointer bug but googling those method names doesn't return any KB article.

Comment: Thanks. We moved to 2012 some time afterwards and I completely forgot about this question :)

Comment: Specifically the error seems to be "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000" inside `sqlservr.exe!CClrXvarProxy::EnsureBufferInit` so looks like a null pointer bug but googling those method names don't return any KB article.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks :) !! I have added that info to my answer. Did you capture that using WinDBG and the sqlservr.pdb public symbols?

Comment: Attached VS to it  with symbols configured and put a break point on KernelBase.dll!RaiseException. It seemed to be hit quite a few times but that was the first one. The info about the access violation gets printed to the output window in VS.